# Criteria Order by subclass in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

```
riteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Order.class)
                .setProjection(Projections.distinct(
                    Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("this.id"))
                    .add(Projections.property("this.creationDate"))
                    .add(Projections.property("this.effectiveDate"))
                    .add(Projections.property("this.modificationDate"))))
                .createAlias("this.consultation", "c")
                .createAlias("c.institution", "institution")
```

I'm trying to use order.consultation.institution. Is it possible?
To achieve this...

```
crit.addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.desc("institution"));
```

If I want other subclass I would like to access (multilevel). For instance, If I have something like Object A contains Object B contains Object C etc. So, A->B->C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.createAlias("this.consultation", "c")
.setProjection(Projections.distinct(
Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("this.id"))
.add(Projections.property("this.creationDate"))
.add(Projections.property("c.institution"))

...

crit.addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.desc("c.institution"));
```

For second question, you access litteraly your sublcass and their method by doing this (for instance A->B->C)

```
.createAlias("this.a", "a")
.createAlias("a.b", "b")
.createAlias("b.c", "c")
```

And so on..